# NLP pre-processing function optimization as it is extremely low on 92Mb data set

Tags: python, performance, natural-language-processing

I have a data set that is of 300,000 rows approximately and two columns, each row contains a string, some might be larger than others. All in all, the data set in a `pkl` format is of 92Mb. It is a bit, but I reckon not too much either.

This is the pre-processing function I have:

```py
import nltk
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import string
import re
import contractions
from unidecode import unidecode

# Just making up a data frame for MWE
df = pd.DataFrame([["Hello my name is XXXX", "What is your name?"], ["I don't know", "I know somenoe who is funny"], ["What is your favorite food", "What are you talking about"]],
                    columns=['title', 'body'])


lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
pos_tag_dict = {"J": wordnet.ADJ, "N": wordnet.NOUN, "V": wordnet.VERB, "R": wordnet.ADV}
local_stopwords = set(stopwords.words('english'))
additional_stopwords = ["http", "u", "get", "like", "let", "nan"]
words_to_keep = ["i'" " i ", "me", "my", "we", "our", "us"]
local_stopwords.update(additional_stopwords)
for word in words_to_keep:
  if word in local_stopwords:
    words_to_keep.remove(word)

def lemmatize_pos_tagged_text(text, lemmatizer, post_tag_dict):
    sentences = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
    new_sentences = []

    for sentence in sentences:
        sentence = sentence.lower()
        new_sentence_words = []    #one pos_tuple for sentence
        pos_tuples = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)) 

        for word_idx, word in enumerate(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)):
            nltk_word_pos = pos_tuples[word_idx][1]
            wordnet_word_pos = pos_tag_dict.get(
                                nltk_word_pos[0].upper(), None)
            if wordnet_word_pos is not None:
              new_word = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, wordnet_word_pos)
            else:
              new_word = lemmatizer.lemmatize(word)

            new_sentence_words.append(new_word)

    new_sentence = " ".join(new_sentence_words)
    new_sentences.append(new_sentence)

    return " ".join(new_sentences)

def processing_steps(df):

    new_data = {}

    for column in df.columns:

        # Tokenization
        results = df[column].apply(word_tokenize)

        # Lowercasing each word within the list
        results = results.apply(lambda x: [word.lower() for word in x])

        # Removing stopwords
        results = results.apply(lambda tokens: [word for word in tokens if word.isalpha() and word not in local_stopwords])

        # Replace diacritics
        results = results.apply(lambda x: [unidecode(word, errors="preserve") for word in x])

        # Expand contractions
        results = results.apply(lambda x: [" ".join([contractions.fix(expanded_word) for expanded_word in word.split()]) for word in x])

        # Remove numbers
        results = results.apply(lambda x: [re.sub(r'\d+', '', word) for word in x])

        # Remove punctuation except period
        results = results.apply(lambda x: [re.sub('[%s]' % re.escape(string.punctuation.replace('.', '')), '' , word) for word in x])


        # Remove double space
        results = results.apply(lambda x: [re.sub(' +', ' ', word) for word in x])


        # Lemmatization
        #results.apply(lambda x: print(x))
        results = results.apply(lambda x: [lemmatize_pos_tagged_text(word, lemmatizer, pos_tag_dict) for word in x])

        new_data[column] = results

    new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)

    return new_df

print(processing_steps(df))
```

This works as expected on the pre-processing aspect. It’s just that when I give it a larger data set, it would take more than 30 min to process everything. So there is clearly something I’m missing and that I could re-arrange to optimize it, but I don’t know what specifically.

How would you optimize it?

Comment: This is on my queue to review. But would be nice if you can profile all the steps in `preprossing_steps()` using `perf_counter`. To make this easy I would pull out `result.apply` in it's own function and decorate it with my `timeit` decorator. Hopefully it will tell me what is hogging all those CPU cycles. When it comes to performance always measure before you optimize.

Comment: I started to review your code. Turns out I dont have your pickle files which is a blocker for me as I cannot run your code. Also, the question is about performance and since no sane performance optimization can happen without measurement, I cannot proceed. One thing that jumps out as potential bottleneck is Regex being created again and again. Since your pattern is static. Use re.compile to create a pattern. Regex initialization is very expensive as it has to compile the pattern first. Matching with a pre-compiled regex is very cheap. Having regex compilation in your hot path is a bad idea.